# Authorize.net API error: Class 'Goetas\Xsd\XsdToPhp\Jms\Handler\BaseTypesHandler' not found

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, authorize.net

I am using the "Quick Usage Example (with Charge Credit Card - Authorize and Capture)" here:
https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php

and I am running into this error where I have my code hosted on heroku:

> PHP Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. in Unknown on line 0

To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead.

> local.ERROR: exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Class 'Goetas\Xsd\XsdToPhp\Jms\Handler\BaseTypesHandler' not found'
>   in
>   /app/vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/net/authorize/api/controller/base/ApiOperationBase.php:82

When I test transactions on my localhost (using laravel 5.1), I am able to create successful transactions and have not received this error. This only occurs on my live server.

On Postman, I only receive this error:

> Class 'Goetas\Xsd\XsdToPhp\Jms\Handler\BaseTypesHandler' not found

This class and other files do exist in vendors/goetas/...., but I do not understand why this is occuring.

I have not found any instance of anyone dealing with this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did it worked for you? If it was worked then please post your code here, it will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

A hotfix for this issue has been posted in the [Authorize.net php-sdk's issue queue on GitHub](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/138).

You have to update your composer.json to use a specific commit from the xsd2php library.

```
"require-dev": {        
    "goetas/xsd2php": "2.0.x-dev#fdc2ab0bb3f2b3ab796ca567cf8c0f3446a7ea3a",
}
```

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks for that!